# Como calcular notas de prova?

Tags: python, algoritmo

Estou escrevendo um código que imprime a nota de um aluno conforme o número de questões que ele acerta. Mas preciso que o programa faça o cálculo numa quantidade de vezes específica. O programa deve receber a quantidade de questões na prova, o gabarito da prova (a prova é objetiva), a quantidade de alunos que fizeram a prova e a resposta de cada aluno. O programa deve imprimir a nota de cada aluno, sendo que o aluno recebe 1 ponto por questão correta. Exemplo:

Entrada:

```
5
ABCDD
2
ABCDD
ACCDE
```

Saída:

```
5
3
```

Outro exemplo:

Entrada:

```
3
DAA
3
ABA
DDA
BBC
```

Saída:

```
1
2
0
```

Como estou fazendo:

```
questões = int(raw_input())
gabarito = raw_input()
alunos = int(raw_input())
resposta = raw_input()
nota = 0
for i in resposta:
   if i == r in gabarito:
      nota = nota + 1
   print nota
```

Minha dificuldade está em fazer o código receber a quantidade de entradas especificadas. Daria certo definindo uma função, ou não precisa? Como proceder?

Comment: Não entendi essa linha: `if i == r in gabarito` . Além disso, seu código não roda-- está sem parêntesis nos `raw_input`.

Comment: Se o item da resposta estiver contido no gabarito. Erro de digitação.

Comment: Você entende que você está procurando um Boolean dentro de uma String nessa linha? Além disso, o que é `r`?

Comment: Não entendo, irei estudar o assunto. 'r' seria a representação variável de cada item na resposta. Cometi um erro. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na questão, é uma quantidade `x` de alunos passada pelo exercício, é nessa parte que você está errando.

Quando pegar a quantidade de alunos que responderam o gabarito, tem que entrar em uma estrutura de repetição para capturar todos os alunos e apos isso verificar o gabarito de cada um.

Outra coisa, ficou um pouco estranha a sua condição `if i == r in gabarito`, o `in` é usando para procurar o valor dentro da `string` ou `array` ex:

```
if 'msg' in "Name of message is msg, end of string":
```

A condição procurará a `string` "msg" dentro da outra `string`, então no caso do gabarito, mesmo que a ordem esteja errada, o código consideraria como correto.

Código resolvido:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# o método input() recolhe valores inteiros, não há
# necessidade de conversão
# o raw_input() recolhe strings, mas só é disponível
# para o python2.x, no python3.x, só possui o método
# input() recolhendo string
quest = input()
gabar = raw_input()
aluno = input()

for x in range(aluno):
    resp = raw_input()
    nota = 0
    for x in range(len(resp)):
        if gabar[x] == resp[x]:
            nota+=1

    print nota
```

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado!